# How to increment django integer field from view?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views, django-database

I'm creating a Django 1.8.4 web application to submit links with up vote and down vote functionality. But every time I click the up vote button, it applies on the last link submitted. I'm using forms to do it. The form is quite normal:

```
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        exclude = ("vote_type", "vote_date",)
```

here's the model:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
    up_votes    = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, db_index=True)
    down_votes  = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, db_index=True)
    ...

class Vote(models.Model):
    UP, DOWN = range(2)
    TYPE_CHOICES = [(UP, "Upvote"), (DOWN, "DownVote")]

    voter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link, related_name='votes')
    vote_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, db_index=True, null=True)
    vote_date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now=True)
```

and the view handles voting: (it's still so simple and stupid I guess)

```
class VoteFormView(FormView):
    form_class = VoteForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        link = get_object_or_404(Link, pk=form.data["link"])
        user = self.request.user
        prev_votes = Vote.objects.filter(voter=user, link=link)
        has_voted = (prev_votes.count()>0)

        if not has_voted:
            Vote.objects.get_or_create(voter=user, link=link)
            Link.objects.filter(pk=form.data["link"]).update(up_votes=F('up_votes')+1)
            print("+voted")
        else:
            pass
        return redirect("home")
```

The idea here was to check if the current user has voted for the link, if she didn't so, then increment the up_votes field of corresponding link object. But now it only increments the last link.object.up_votes.

Comment: the form.data["link"], is coming with  the correct pk ?

Comment: You don't seem to have done anything to tie a form to a specific link.

Comment: Exactly that's the problem. I've added `print link` and it prints same link.title no matter on which up vote button I click. hoc can I fix this now? I mean How can I send correct pk to the view?

Comment: It was really stupid problem! I had forgot to close <form> tag in my template! so the right pk couldn't be send! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

As you may see in comments, the problem caused by wrong pk sent to the views, and it was my mistake to close  tag in my template. Just for the record I paste here that part of template code:

```
{% for link in object_list %}
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'vote' %}" class="vote_form">
    <li> 
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" id="id_link" name="link" class="hidden_id" value="{{ link.pk }}"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="id_link" name="voter" class="hidden_id" value="{{ user.pk }}"/>
        <button>+</button>
        [{{ link.up_votes }}] 
        <a href="{{ link.url }}">
            <h3>{{ link.title }}</h3>
        </a> 
        <a href="{% url 'link_detail' pk=link.id slug=link.title|slugify %}">
            Comments
        </a>
        <p>
            Submitted by: <a href="{% url 'profile' slug=link.submitter%}"> {{ link.submitter }}</a>
        </p>
    </li>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```